# Fuse Question and Surge Protectors

Tags: protection, fuses, surge-protection, varistor

I am doing a DIY PDU project for my college using an Arudino and I have 8 16Amp relays that are controlled via the board. I want to make some sort of surge protector for it as well.

Basically I want to know what fuses must I use for the mains input and what Varistors should be used. There will be one 220V input plug and that will feed 8 220V 16 Amp plugs on the outputs controlled by relays.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a single 15A circuit breaker in series initially instead of a fuse. Fuses at 16A could cook and can be problematic. Also, using the relay at stated rating could have heat problems. For a properly designed device, protection should be designed for the power tap as well as the load.

As for a surge protector, MOV's are the most common to use and most common to fail. You would probably want your VPR around 600V to prevent any unwanted early failures.

Both the circuit breaker and surge protection should be as close to the power inlet as possible, in front of everything else.